# Insert into using a default value if select returns null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a non-null field I wish to populate from another table.  Trouble is the query into the other table may return null.  How do I get a value (0 will do) when the query returns null?
My query is:

```
update Packages
    set PackageTypeId = (SELECT TOP 1 PackageTypeId
                         FROM PackageTypes
                         WHERE Packages.PackageTypeName = PackageTypes.Name
                         ORDER BY PackageTypeId ASC)
```

I tried using coalesce, but it still fails:

```
update Packages
     set PackageTypeId = (SELECT TOP 1 coalesce(PackageTypeId, 0) as id
                          FROM PackageTypes
                          WHERE Packages.PackageTypeName = PackageTypes.Name
                          ORDER BY PackageTypeId ASC)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
update Packages 
set PackageTypeId = coalesce((SELECT TOP 1 PackageTypeId FROM PackageTypes 
                              WHERE Packages.PackageTypeName = PackageTypes.Name 
                              ORDER BY PackageTypeId ASC), 0)
```

Comment: That makes bucket loads of sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend UPDATE FROM statement combined with ISNULL function:

```
UPDATE
    Packages
SET
    Packages.PackageTypeId = ISNULL(PackageTypes.PackageTypeId,0)
FROM
    Packages
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            PackageTypeId,
            Name
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    PackageTypeId,
                    Name,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY PackageTypeId ASC) R
                FROM
                    PackageTypes
            ) X
        WHERE
            R = 1
    ) PackageTypes
ON
    Packages.PackageTypeName = PackageTypes.Name
```

Note: Subquery return smallest PackageTypeId for each Name in PackageType

Comment: but the order by and top 1 part is lost

Comment: order by and top 1 is not necessary in this case - mathing rows is done by join. BTW. I'm not sure, but this form should be faster than finding top 1 row for each ID.

Comment: the order by and top 1 suggest that there are multiple `PackageTypeId` per `PackageTypeName`. the original query chooses the one with the least ID, yours not.

Comment: You are right! I've modified query above according to this.